# How to redirect data of dmesg using Runtime.exec?

Tags: java, android, kernel, logging

**Problem 1:**
I want to redirect the kernel log to other file using my app.
How to properly execute this? The code is something like below:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dmesg > /data/kernel_log.txt");
```

**Problem 2:**
I want to clear the kernel log using my app. How to correct the below code;

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dmesg -c");
```

**Note1:**
My goal is to get all the log of the kernel(dmesg) from START to LATEST.
Since dmesg has buffer size limitation and I don't want to rebuild the kernel
just to resize the buffer.

**Note2:** this is very related to;
[android : how to run a shell command from within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054973/android-how-to-run-a-shell-command-from-within-code)

**Note3:** Currently I am using a device with a ENG mode build, which means this is rooted am I correct?

**Logcat Error Message:**

```
11-11 20:18:47.910: E/DmesgGetterService(2885): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [dmesg > /data/kernel_log.txt] Working Directory: null Environment: null
...
11-11 20:19:07.920: E/DmesgGetterService(2885): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
...
```

Comment: I have never worked with android, but if it is as similar to "Desktop-Linux" as I suspect, you should be able to obtain the dmesg-info from the /proc filesystem. IIRC dmesg is just an abbreviation for printing the virtual file /proc/kmesg.

Comment: Yes, I can get the kernel log using:    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dmesg");

Comment: The problem is I cannot redirect the output to other file. I can make use of the FileOutputStream but this may take lots of memory usage since I am going to loop line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the dmesg log in different method. Using the AlarmManager to run a service in the specified interval I fetch the log from the kernel then find the last line I copied from previous run then append the new logs. That's it!

Comment: Can you please post the detailed solution. I am trying to redirect the output of dmesg to a file in sdcard. I have included the permissions to write and read from sdcard. ( Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dmesg > /sdcard/file_name.txt"). Also, is it necessary to have root permissions to run this command ?